# Isomorphism Gaussian and Polynomial Quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

How does $$\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+i) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1,2+x)$$ follow formally from the fact that $$\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)?$$

Comment: What is the problem? Taking repeated quotients of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? Otherwise, you see that the quotients have to be isomorphic because $(2+i)$ corresponds to $(2+x)$ under the usual isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm First, your comment is hardly readable. Second, such a detailed comment surely deserves to be upgraded to nicely written, spaced answer.

Comment: @Timbuc: I removed my comment and made it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\ZZ}{{\mathbb Z}}$ 
$\newcommand{\ideal}[1]{{\mathfrak #1}}$
It can be transformed

$$
\begin{multline}
\ZZ[i]/(2+i)\ZZ[i] = (\ZZ[x]/(x^2+1))/((2+\bar{x})\ZZ[x]/(x^2+1)) =  \\ =(\ZZ[x]/(x^2+1))/((2+x) \ZZ[x]/(x^2+1)) = (\ZZ[x]/(x^2+1))/((2+x,x^2+1)/(x^2+1)) = \\
 = \ZZ[x]/(2+x,x^2+1)
\end{multline}
$$

using $(M/P)/(N/P) = M/N$ for $A$-modules $M \supseteq N \supseteq P$ (Noether isomorphism theorem) and $\ideal{a} (A/\ideal{b}) = (\ideal{a} + \ideal{b})/\ideal{b}$ for $\ideal{a}, \ideal{b} \subseteq A$ two ideals of $A$.

Comment: I don't believe that $(2+i)$ is well defined in the RHS of the first line. It should be $(2+x)$ -- or $(2+\bar{x})$ with $\bar{x}$ the class of $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$, if you want to be precise.

Comment: I edited it according to your proposal.